# Git revert merge plus one commit on top to re-merge again

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, git-revert

I did huge merge, from ide (intellij idea), so when all conflicsts were resolved, and som code were modifed, and I did commit (the merge one), then noticed that there are two files are remaning to commit. So I did commit again.

There are two questionss:

1. Why did I have second commit. Is that because IDE somehow missed `added` commit to merge (ide not smart enought to see that all those changes in the context of one merge?). Is that what happens if I forgot to `add` file to `index` if I would go with command line after merge (?)
2. How I could revert those two commits so that I could do one pure merge?

Like the pic:

> [commit1] <- [megre-commit] <- [before-commit] | (master)

I tried `git rebase -i rebase HEAD~2` (just first idea to combine two commits) but that showed all those 121 commists - one commit1 and 120 from merge-commit.

**Basically I want to add my 'lost'/'detached' [commit1] to the [merge-commit] and have one merge.**

UPDATE:
I do not have my code with me to try, but does this make sense?

```
 // revert two commits to have one
 1. git reset --soft HEAD~ 
 2. git revert -m 1 merge-commit
 3. git commit
```

I expect to see changes again, all those 1 + 120 commits. But then how would I merge

```
 // move my merged stuff into new branch 
 4. git push origin -u new_branch

 // move back on history in master branch
 5. git reset --hard before-commit
 6. git merge new_branch
 7. git push -f origin master
```

Then this git merge new_branch would go without any conflicts, since it i alredy been merged.. so that may not show true (hi)story from where it was merged from.. but at least end result should the same. Theoretically.

?

Comment: And this kids, is why using the IDE's Git integration is always at your own risk, and why using the CLI is almost always preferred. You **might** be able to get away with an interactive rebase to squash the commits together (if you didn't push your commits yet). However, make sure it works with merge commits, because I'm not sure.

Comment: IDE just goes well with merge so I see nice pic what has been changed and how.

Comment: I follow the "look, don't touch" rule with any Git GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You have many questions in one post.

Why you ended up with the second commit? Most probably because of the quirks of the IntelliJ's git plugin. It doesn't make a good distinction between the staging and working areas, which might lead to the cases like yours if you edit a merged file after the resolution. Nothing dangerous there, just extra care before pushing your changes upstream. It is still much more convenient to resolve conflicts with IDE unless they are very trivial.

As for the fixing, your first attempt to do an interactive rebase was in the right direction. I am not sure what is the second `rebase` you are referring to in your example, but the `git rebase -i HEAD~2` should have shown you last two commits, where you could squash the last into the first.

Another option could be `git reset HEAD^ && git commit --amend` which is essentially the same.

Comment: That sounds right I just remember that with git rebase -i HEAD~2 showed me many commits from that merge-commit. i will it try it on real project.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked on simple demo.

So yes, indeed the way IDE/IntelliJ Idea works - it does merge, but once you done editing in that Merge Tool and then in main code editor (not yet commting anything) keeping chaning the code, then wen commit from UI/change-list - it will make first commit(the merge itself), but some files will be left in the change-list. So then you may commit them as sepparate commit. (that wat I did..)

So to fix the problem from command line.

Maybe a little bit clumsy

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1   // revert left-over commit 
git stash                 // safe left-over commit to stas
git reset --soft HEAD~1   (get back merged content from merge-commit)

 git stash pop           // get stased


then during conflct accept all from stashed (since we know that those changes were made on top. so noew we have comined content from merge commit and that extra commit)

git commt -m "merged stuff'   // left over of first commit
```

Well then having one commit.. I can merge it to whatever I want.

Like I could make my "merge" that I should have had if I did it right:

```
git checkout newone -b master 
git reset --hard HEAD~1

git checkout master 
git reset --hard HEAD~1

git merge newone // accepting all changes
```